# Surjectivity when $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$ ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$, and assume that $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$. Prove that a linear map $F:V\to W$ cannot be surjective.

For me it is obvious $F$ cannot be surjective because not all elements in $W$ will have a match in $V$. However I am having trouble on coming up with a more decent proof.

**Question**: How can I prove the statement?

Thanks in advance!
Added after Dave comment:

$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(V)<\dim(W)$

so

$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))<\dim(W)$

Comment: What theorem do you know that discusses the dimension of the image of a linear map?

Comment: $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(V)$. Found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: @uniquesolution Let $L:V\to W$ be a linear map, and assume that $dimV=dimW$. Assume in addition that the Kernel of $L$ is $\{0\}$. Then the image of $L$ is all of $W$.

Comment: @Dave Please Check up the edit.

Comment: Good. Now use the fact that $\dim(\ker(T))$ is a nonnegative integer. So if you have $n+m<k$ for $n,m,k\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$ you must have $n<k$.

Comment: @Dave Could you answer the question with all the elements you brought in. I do not think it is right to update the answer in the question section. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells us that $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(V)$. Since $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$ we have:
$$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(V)<\dim(W)$$
Since dimensions are nonnegative integers, we must then have
$$\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))<\dim(W)\implies \dim(\operatorname{im}(T))<\dim(W)$$
Hence, $T$ cannot be surjective, since surjectivity is equivalent to $\operatorname{im}(T)=W$, which is impossible if $\operatorname{im}(T)$ and $W$ have different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You arrive correctly at
$$
\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))<\dim(W)
$$
Now
$$
\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))<\dim(W)-\dim(\ker(T))\le\dim(W)
$$

There is no reason why $\dim(\ker(T))$ should be $0$, but it's not relevant, because $\dim(\ker(T))\ge0$.